# Excel to word Align picture

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a report that is built from Excel and outputs in Word, I also have a picture called "Picture 7". My question is once this is pasted into word from excel is there anyway to center align the picture?

the picture is copied over as part of a range of cells. So I would need to reference the picture in word.

It is centered on the range of cells but does not quite come out center in the word document

Edit: Currently I am trying this

```
For Each shp In oDoc.Shapes
    If Left(shp.Name, 7) = "RN Logo" Then
        shp.Left = wdShapeCenter
    End If
Next
```

But this is just putting the picture in the top left, I think because of the table it is pasted with I may need to do an absolute position on it.

Edit 2:I have found a work around but it is just a large If/Else and absolute positioning, snippet below

```
Sub Update_RN_Logo_Location()

For Each shp In oDoc.Shapes
    If Left(shp.Name, 7) = "RN Logo" Then
        If Right(shp.Name, 1) = 1 Then
            shp.Left = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(2.4)
        Else
            shp.Left = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(0.75)
        End If
    ElseIf Left(shp.Name, 4) = "UKAS" Then
        If Right(shp.Name, 1) = 1 Then
            shp.Left = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(1.25)
        ElseIf Right(shp.Name, 1) = 2 Then
            shp.Left = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(2.5)
        ElseIf Right(shp.Name, 1) = 3 Then
            shp.Left = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(0)
        ElseIf Right(shp.Name, 1) = 4 Then
            shp.Left = oWord.CentimetersToPoints(2.5)
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Picture of the document with some removed sensitive information

[image: Word Document In Question]

Comment: I have added the code I am using atm. Its not quite behaving correctly atm

Comment: Does it lose alignment from excel to word? As in, it's aligned properly in excel but loses that on the way over?

Comment: It does seem to stay roughly in the same spot but it has to be center aligned and its rather tedious trying to get it in exactly the right spot, was hoping there would (should?) be a way to do via code.

Comment: I could use an aboslute picture alignment but then I would have a long if else statement as pictures are different sizes on different pages

Comment: can you add a screen-shot of your word document?

Comment: added the picture. The logo on that is centered using the code above the picture (if/Else)

Comment: Just brainstorming - Have you thought about maybe creating a word template which has all of your default images, stuff in there which shows up in every report. Then copy over the relevant data. This would avoid worrying about the image alignment as it would already be set up. You could keep the template on the server so that anyone could access it as well. Or do you really need to use it as a word document. Could you convert the worksheet to a pdf?

Comment: The whole idea of what I am developing is to move away from templates (previous system used templates) so that it is easier to make changes as and where needed. It has to be in a format that 1) everyone is able to use (variing levels of IT Literate users) and 2) is editable as it will never come out 100%, their is a certain amount that would be ridiculous to program and take 5 seconds for a human. thanks for the thoughts though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there are two issues here. First, graphics in word have an anchor. When the graphic is pasted, the anchor for it is placed in the table created by Excel's cells. This throws off positioning.

Second, I suggest using the `Shape.RelativeHorizontalPosition` property, which will allow your `Shape.Left` property to give you a true center alignment relative to another page element.

In the code below I am positioning the graphic relative to the document's margins, but there are other choices:

[Word 2007 WdRelativeHorizontalPosition Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb237984(v=office.12).aspx)

This enumeration will also work for Word 2010 and 2013.

To assure proper placement of the logo graphic, insert a carriage return at the top of the document **prior to pasting in your logo and table** (make sure this carriage return has no indents or styles that apply spatial formatting):

```
 Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
 Selection.InsertBefore vbCr
```

Then paste in the graphic and table and run this code:

```
 For Each shp In oDoc.Shapes
     If Left(shp.Name, 7) = "RN Logo" Then
         With shp
           .Select
           Selection.Cut
           Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
           Selection.Paste 'places graphic on carriage return before table
           .RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionMargin
           .Left = wdShapeCenter
           .RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionMargin
           '.Top = measurement of choice
         End With
     End If
 Next
```

Comment: Thanks for a nice explanation of what is going on and an example code, I would assume that my Pointer (curser on word doc) after this code will be at the top of the document so after I will have to do something like Selection.EndKey Unit:=wdStory to get back to the end of the document to carry on with the next pages?

Comment: @99moorem Yes, that will place your insertion point at the end of the document. One could also set a `range` and/or insert a bookmark, but the use case would decide how complex the navigation code needs to be. For example, I might want the logo to be (somewhat) resistant to the user moving it out of position. If that were the case, I might turn on the document's first page header, go there, paste the logo in that header, go back to the main document, adjust the table, and then go to the end of the document. That would give the logo added protection, but also require additional navigation code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply center-aligning the default paragraph (or adding a text box) and pasting in the picture? Keep the picture separate from everything else. You may need to set a text run-around as well.

This is slightly-modified recorded Word VBA

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture FileName:= _
        "C:\Users\user\Desktop\01.jpg", LinkToFile:=False, _
        SaveWithDocument:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: I only require the picture itself to be centered, in my picutre example above I know that the above code would be ok but on some sheets the paragraph will be left aligned and picture still required to align centre

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a "Control+A" select all and then allign everything to center:

```
Sub Testing()
    'Select All:
      Selection.WholeStory
    'Center Align All:
      Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
End Sub
```

Comment: This report is anywhere between 50-250 pages long and most of it is not center aligned, I believe this would format the whole document?

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to insert pictures from outside Excel/Word;
You can position them exactly in the paragraph you want:

```
Sub M_snb()
  ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(5).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture("G:\Excel_.bmp").Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 1
End Sub
```

Comment: Would the paragraph aspect still work as it is all in tables? this may be the best option for me to implement.